# How to update a record without loading an orm?

Tags: orm, kohana-3.3

Is there a way to update a record in a table using an ORM model without any extra queries?

I know that I can simply use DB object to do a raw query, but I would like to do it with an ORM object.

I have the following code.

```
$orm = ORM::factory("myobject",1);
$orm->name = "new name";
$orm->save();
```

the problem of the code is that it executes a select query then executes an update query.

I've tried the following as well.

```
ORM::factory("myobject")->values(array("id"=>1, "name"=>"my new name"))-save();
```

the problem of this query is that the ORM executes "**show full columns from myobject**"

How do I make an update query on an ORM object without executing any extra queries?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get the `show full columns for ..` query is that you don't have defined `$_table_columns`, where the table column data for that object is stored. Kohana needs to know these so you can set values to that object.

E.g.

```
protected $_table_columns = array(
    'id'   => array('type' => 'int'),
    'name' => array('type' => 'string'),
    .......
);
```

And to answer your question. The second way seems like the right way to do it :) As soon as you've done the above the 'extra' query should be gone